# paramMap item always returns null using Angular 8 routing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm using Angular 8 to get some params or data from the route but it's always empty.
My component is inside a lazyloaded module named 'message'.

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```js
...

{
  path: 'message',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import('./systems/message/message.module').then(
      m => m.MessageModule
    )
},

...
```

**message-routing.module.ts:**

```js
...

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MessageIndexComponent,
    children: [{ path: ':folder', component: ComponentMessageListComponent }]
  },
  { path: 'add', component: MessageAddComponent },
  { path: 'list', component: MessageIndexComponent }
];

...
```

**component-message-list.component.ts:**

```js
...

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('folder'));
   // Change list on date change
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params.get('folder'));
  });
}

...
```

Both consoles are returning NULL when routing to this address:

> /message/inbox

**UPDATE:**

I'm navigating to the route by writing the address directly to the browser:

> http://127.0.0.1:4200/message/inbox

or by an anchor tag

**message-index.component.html**

```html
...

  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex p-3" routerLink="inbox" routerLinkActive="active">
    Inbox
  </a>
...
```

And always the param is null

Comment: How do you navigate to the route with the data? Can you add that code?

Comment: @AmitChigadani By writing the route in the address bar or using an anchor tag. I added this to the question

Comment: Can you share MessageIndexComponent html code?

Comment: @Chellappanவ The anchor tag added from that file

Answer (score 0):

<s>I had to get the firstChild params not the parent. The previews code was returning the params of the parent.</s>

This code works:

```js
this.route.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params.get('folder'));
  });
```

**UPDATE:**
The problem was that I forgot to replace the child component tag in the parent with 'router-outlet' then the child component was inserting in the parent without router!

Thanks everyone

Comment: why paramMap and not simply params ? `this.route.params.subscribe( ...)`

Comment: @Stavm params property is deprecated and will be removed in the future versions. https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#activatedroute-props

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams[key]
```

Comment: Hi, this works but I cannot explain why the normal way doesn't. Do you know?

Comment: @They_Call_Me_Joe does subscription work when you change route? try this one: this.route.snapshot.params['folder'] and tell me if it works